# php loop through 2 arrays to find keys and values that match

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays named investmentprogramscriteria and companyInvestmentProfil:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [investmentprogramcriteriaID] => 20
        [investmentprogramID] => 21
        [criteriaID] => 59
        [criteriaIsMatchedIf] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [investmentprogramcriteriaID] => 21
        [investmentprogramID] => 21
        [criteriaID] => 57
        [criteriaIsMatchedIf] => 1
    )

)


Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [investmentprofileID] => 1
        [companyID] => 27
        [criteriaID] => 54
        [investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [investmentprofileID] => 2
        [companyID] => 27
        [criteriaID] => 57
        [investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [investmentprofileID] => 3
        [companyID] => 27
        [criteriaID] => 58
        [investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [investmentprofileID] => 4
        [companyID] => 27
        [criteriaID] => 59
        [investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer] => 1
    )

)
```

If the last 2 KEYS AND THEIR VALUES from the first array are found in the second array, code should return match,
else should return not match.

I make an attempt to resolve this with array functions, but nothing worked and now I am trying to solve it with php, but no luck so far.

I am trying with:

```
foreach ($investmentprogramscriteria as $programcriteria) {
    //foreach($companyInvestmentProfil as $profile) {
        if (($programcriteria['criteriaID'] == $companyInvestmentProfil[$i]['criteriaID']) && ($programcriteria['criteriaIsMatchedIf'] == $companyInvestmentProfil[$i]['investmentprofileCriteriaAnswer']))  {
        $match = "Match";                              
    } else {
       $match = "Not Match";
       continue;
// }                                
}

                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is use foreach twice !!!

```
foreach ($investmentprogramscriteria  as $value) {
    foreach ($companyInvestmentProfil as $v) {
        if($v["criteriaID"] == $value["criteriaID"]) echo "match<br>";
        else echo "not Match<br>";
    }    
}
```

Comment: Like this, I get bunch of match and / or not match, depending from the key. Even if one value is not matched, code should return not match. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: This will return a match for _every_ `$companyInvestmentProfil` value that matches _any_ `$investmentprogramscriteria` value. I think OP is after a 1-to-1 match

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Your code contains a bug:

```
$programcriteria['criteriaID'] == $companyInvestmentProfil[$i]['criteriaID']
```

the variable `$i` is never defined. You probably meant to write something like:

```
// assign keys to $i
foreach ($investmentprogramscriteria as $i => $programcriteria) {
}
```

In which case, either using the `array_slice` + `array_keys` approach below, with or without the `array_intersect_assoc` approach should work, if you use them on the `$programcriteria` and `$companyInvestmentProfil[$k]` arrays respectively.

---

What you're basically looking for is [the `array_intersect_assoc` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php). That function returns an array with all key-value pairs that are present in both arrays:

```
$intersect = array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2);
```

To see how many key-value pairs match, just `count($intersect);`

To see if the last 2 keys of the first array matched, simply write this:

```
$lastKeys = array_slice(array_keys($array1), -2);
if (isset($intersect[$lastKeys[0]]) && isset($intersect[$lastKeys[1])) {
    return 'match';
}
return 'no match';
```

Check the manual [on `array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) for details.

Comment: give me a moment to try this

Comment: $intersect didn't worked. However ,if you can notice, my keynames are not the same. Do you think that that may be the reason why intersect give wrong results?

Comment: Set up a fiddle with what you tried. I've used `$array1` and `$array2` as variable names, but I suspect what you need/want is `$investmentprogramscriteria[0]` and `$companyInvestmentProfil[0]` instead

Comment: @user2417624: I've also spotted an issue in the code you originally posted, updated my answer and added some suggestions on how to use the functions I mentioned correctly

Comment: I was googling where I can create  fiddle, when I notice your second comment. The [$i] variable is setted elsewhere in the code, because there may be many investment programs array, so I was trying to use it, but it is the one that cause the issues. However, If I use [0] as you suggest, it will check only the first key-value par and then it will stop.

Comment: @user2417624: Yes, that's why I went on to suggest an assoc `foreach`. I don't know what the full code looks like though, so perhaps consider posting more inf

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array("a" => "greens", "reds", "blues", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

 if(is_array($result)){
    echo 'match';
 }else{
    echo 'not match';
 }
```